# auto hide a list view index side bar and activated when scroll the listview android?

Tags: java, android

> auto hide a list view index side bar and activated when scroll the listview android?
>   here i put the sample code for doing a list view items and the indexed side bar

activity_main.xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  android:baselineAligned="false" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_fruits"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >
</ListView>

<ScrollView 
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/side_index"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#c3c3c3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

and
side_index_item.xml.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/side_list_item"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textColor="@color/text_color"    
/>
```

and MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 Map<String, Integer> mapIndex;
 ListView fruitList;
 private static String[] alphabetArray = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",    "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
 Map<Integer,String> alphaIndexMap;
 TextView getSelectedAlphabet;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] fruits = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruits_array);

    Arrays.asList(fruits);

    fruitList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_fruits);
    fruitList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruits));

    //getIndexList(fruits);
    getIndexList(alphabetArray,fruits);
    displayIndex();

}

//int j = 0;
private void getIndexList(String[] alphabet,String[] fruits) {
    mapIndex = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    alphaIndexMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {

        String alphaLetter = alphabet[i];

            int j = startWithAlphabetIndex(mapIndex,fruits,alphaLetter);
            if(j!=-1){
             mapIndex.put(alphabet[i], j);
             alphaIndexMap.put(j, alphabet[i]);
            }
            else{

                for(int k = i+1;k<alphabet.length;k++){
                    alphaLetter = alphabet[k];
                    j = startWithAlphabetIndex(mapIndex,fruits,alphaLetter);
                    if(j>0){
                        mapIndex.put(alphabet[i], j);
                        alphaIndexMap.put(j, alphabet[i-1]);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }


            }   

    }

}
public int startWithAlphabetIndex(Map<String, Integer> mapIndex, String[] fruits,String alphabet){
    int retValue = -1;
    for(int j =0; j < fruits.length; j++){
        if(fruits[j].startsWith(alphabet)){
            retValue = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    return retValue;
}
private void displayIndex() {
    LinearLayout indexLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.side_index);
    TextView textView;
    //ScrollView scroll;
    List<String> indexList = new ArrayList<String>(mapIndex.keySet());
    for (String index : indexList) {
        textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.side_index_item, null);
        textView.setText(index);
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        indexLayout.addView(textView);
    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    TextView selectedIndex = (TextView) view;
    fruitList.setSelection(mapIndex.get(selectedIndex.getText()));


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

if anyone have the idea please share..

Comment: use scroll listener on listview

Comment: Thank you Meenal  sharma for your valuable suggestion, its working now